# How to sort child products of configurable products

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

In Magento 2, I want to get the data of configurable child product in ascending order like 1kg, 2kg, 3kg and 4kg but I am getting it like 2kg, 3kg, 4kg and 1kg.

Any help please, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Palani You have the liberty to update the product name whenever you want so change the name or when you are creating the product at time fill the names as per your requirement

Comment: thanks @AbhishekTripathi